# Change cell colors when values are entered

Tags: excel

I am trying to change the cell colors when I enter something in them.

Example: `I enter a value in A1, A5 needs to turn Green/Red/...`

Comment: Conditional Formatting: try googling it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Conditional Formatting with the FormulaIs option....Something like:

**=A1<>""**